# PostMan UI Shows a Variable with a Strikethrough Text After Test

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I run a PostMan query and receive a Bearer Token. The test sets the global variable named `BearerToken` as such:

```
if (responseBody !== "undefined")
{
     tests["Bearer Token = " + responseBody] = true; 
     pm.globals.set("BearerToken", responseBody);  
}
```

When I view the values in the eye button it shows the `Current Value` text with a strikethrough:

[image]

Upon the next query which uses the `BearerToken`, it works.

What is the meaning of the Strikethrough?

Comment: Do you have the same variable `BearerToken`set in a different scope? Variables work in scopes an so if you have something set in a different scope, then the one with the narrowest scope will take precedent and the others would have that strike through. Is there a tool tip?

Comment: The variable was used/created  with a different older collection and my new collection is a separate distinct unit from it. As to a tooltip, no amount of hovering over the area, title or associated pen icon provides a tooltip.

Comment: As an aside, the variable was set by hand in the aforementioned collection and not set programmatically as show in my latest collection.

Comment: If you try and use the `{{BearerToken}}` variable syntax in a request param, for example, you should see another variable in the auto-suggestion list and that would be the one that's overriding the strikethrough one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A strikethrough on a variable would suggest that a variable of the same name is currently in a different scope (Collection, Global or Environment)

By using the `{{..}}` variable syntax in the request, you will be able to a list of the variables with the same name and which one the request is using.

[image]

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#variable-scopes

Comment: Duplication was the issue as you provided. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: We could have presented that information better and in all the places. I've flagged that up with the team. 

Comment: Your initial suggestion about getting a tooltip I believe would be the best vehicle to get that info across. Otherwise I shall wait for the C#/WPF version. ;-) Thanks again.